# mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, mysql

Im having this error **mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 121** when I try to login to the system. here is my code section for particular problem. Does anyone know why this is happen to the code ?

```
if(isset($_POST["loginbtn"]))
{
$uid = $_POST["userid"];
$pword = $_POST["userpass"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Ad_ID = '$uid' AND Ad_Pass = '$pword'
   ");
if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    $_SESSION ["loggedin"] = "true" ;
   $_SESSION ["adid"] = $row ["Ad_ID"];
   $_SESSION ["adname"] = $row ["Ad_Name"];
   $_SESSION ["adaright"] = $row ["Ad_ARight"];

    if($row ["Ad_ARight"]=='write')
        header('Location: HomeScreen.php');
    else if($row ["Ad_ARight"]=='read')
        header('Location: HomeScreenr.php');

}
else
{    
       echo '<div class="alert-message error"><p><b> Invalid username or              
password </b></p></div>';
}
}
?>
<div align="center">
```

Comment: Atleast 1 million posts on StackOverflow deal with this question, look it up

Answer (score 1):

your query has failed, so `mysql_query` has returned a boolean false value.

The best way to figure out what's wrong is to add a error handler.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Ad_ID = '$uid' AND Ad_Pass = '$pword'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the query with proper Ad_ID and Ad_Pass and then see if it displays any result.. Probably the result is blank.

```
SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Ad_ID = '$uid' AND Ad_Pass = '$pword'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls DO NOT use mysql, use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Pls consult documentation, what does mysql_query() return when there is an error?  You will probably find it useful to run mysql_error() for more detail.

Comment: @RichardA I can stick more strictly to dictionary spelling if you feel it improves the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to check with **mysql_num_rows** otherwise check your query using mysql_error().

```
if(isset($_POST["loginbtn"]))
{
$uid = $_POST["userid"];
$pword = $_POST["userpass"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Ad_ID = '$uid' AND Ad_Pass = '$pword'
   ") die(mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
    $_SESSION ["loggedin"] = "true" ;
   $_SESSION ["adid"] = $row ["Ad_ID"];
   $_SESSION ["adname"] = $row ["Ad_Name"];
   $_SESSION ["adaright"] = $row ["Ad_ARight"];

    if($row ["Ad_ARight"]=='write')
        header('Location: HomeScreen.php');
    else if($row ["Ad_ARight"]=='read')
        header('Location: HomeScreenr.php');

}
else
{    
       echo '<div class="alert-message error"><p><b> Invalid username or              
password </b></p></div>';
}
}
?>
```

Please check this code. I am not sure it is working or not.
I think it will working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing the check like this. Check if `$result` was set and returns a value. Then assign the array to `$row`:

```
if(isset($result))
{

   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)

   $_SESSION ["loggedin"] = "true" ;
   $_SESSION ["adid"] = $row ["Ad_ID"];
   $_SESSION ["adname"] = $row ["Ad_Name"];
   $_SESSION ["adaright"] = $row ["Ad_ARight"];

    if($row ["Ad_ARight"]=='write')
        header('Location: HomeScreen.php');
    else if($row ["Ad_ARight"]=='read')
   header('Location: HomeScreenr.php');

}
```

What you can also try is to check if it returns any rows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE Ad_ID = '$uid' AND Ad_Pass = '$pword'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows > 0)
{
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
   //CODE HERE
}
```